# Each value of an array as string variables in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, string

I'm trying to get each value of an array separated in different variables.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT comp,code, MATCH (job) AGAINST ('$offer' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM general_comp ORDER BY score DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql1);
$gen = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Output: Array ( [comp] => Conseil clientèle en assurances [code] => abc [score] => 2

I'd like to have :

```
$comp = "Conseil clientèle en assurances";
$code = "abc";
$score = "2";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@asjoler's answer is quite effective and succinct. But if you want secondary control over the variable names, you can use `list()`. `array_values()` is also needed to get the numerical indexes that `list()` needs while keeping the natural order:

```
$a = array();

$a["comp"] = "Conseil clientèle en assurances";
$a["code"] = "abc";
$a["score"] = 2;

list($comp, $code, $score) = array_values($a);


echo $comp . ", ";
echo $code . ", ";
echo $score;
```

Outputs:

```
Conseil clientèle en assurances
abc
2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extract`

for example:

```
$array = array("color" => "blue",
"size"  => "medium",
"shape" => "sphere");

extract($array);

echo $color."<br>";
echo $size."<br>";
echo $shape."<br>";
```

this outputs:

```
blue
medium
sphere
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you're asnwer is the best !
what if I have several array within an array when using fetch_all 'mysqli_fetch_all($result5)' . How can I extract all the element as variables ?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your array, and convert the values to string like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = strval($value);
}
```

Now your arrays elements are all string.

Comment: OP wants the values to be stored to individual variables outside of an array: `i'm trying to get each value of an array separated in different variables`